# Views: Path component not working in contextual filters

Tags: views

**Details:** I have to display view data on per user basis in a block-view. So i am trying a contextual filter on user id.

Read it somewhere that since blocks doesn't have a path so we will have to use "provide default value" option in setting of contextual filter. All goes well but it seems that filter is not taking the second component from the url.

**Ex:**
If my url is abc.com/user/9 and i set contextual filter to use  "Raw value from URL" and "path component" to 2. It checks filter on "user" not "9".

I tried changing the path component to 1 and 3 it takes "user" only as the value of fliter. Any suggestions here what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: please refer [https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/191916/how-to-ignore-the-first-argument-in-view-contextual-filters](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/191916/how-to-ignore-the-first-argument-in-view-contextual-filters)