# How to ignore the first argument in view contextual filters?

Tags: 7, views, path-aliases

I am having path aliases of the form

```
path/val1/val2/data
```

that are created with `pathauto`. I want to create a view that will be use a contextual filter and that will read only section 3 of the URL. When I set the view path to:

```
path/%/%/data
```

then I need to specify a contextual filter for section 3 (`val2`) that cannot filter my data properly.

My configuration looks like:

[image]
**Filter configuration:**

[image]

So I need the CELEX content filter to match *section 3* of the URL. Can I entirely skip %2 and just filter based on %3? Alternatively, can I declare the second section to be a wildcard in the view path?

When I attempt to `Provide default value` as Bryan Jones suggested, then it seems that default value doesn't work because the context filter actually DOES match the URL section, whereas the default value is provided **when the filter value is NOT in the URL**

What I see after previewing the view is

**Context values:**
[image: Context values]

**Query:**
(Notice the value that I wanted to be `val2`)
[image: Query]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a specific contextual filter called "Global: Null" that you can employ to ignore a path part and leave the query unchanged. You will have to reorder the filters so that Null is in the right position (in your case, the first, since you want to ignore the first % of the path). See the screenshot:

[image: The null filter]

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what I was looking for! A `/dev/null` for context filters :)

Comment: Thank you @peterpoe the `Global: Null` suggestion helped me out a lot.

Answer (score 2):

you can use 'all' to get all values of 'val1'

Exp: path/all/val2/data

to get all values of 'val1', 'val2'

Exp: path/all/all/data

Answer (score 0):

In the contextual filter you can select "Provide default value" From there you can select "Raw value from URL". You then choose the path component.
[image]

I hope that helps!

Comment: please check my updated question, I think I had a typo too. I tried this solution before BUT the thing is that "Provide default value" is triggered when the filter value is NOT in the url. In my case the value `value1` IS in the url but I want to avoid it and work with `value2`

Comment: Provide default argument is triggered if the filter is in the URL as long as you select and option like "Raw value from URL" or "User ID from URL". Using "Raw value from URL" you can choose to only pull value2. Perhaps I'm not understanding.

In the case of path/val1/val2/data you would choose path component 3. That should use val2 as the argument in which the view is filtered on.

Comment: Did that too, see edit, but still getting odd results. Could it be because the path uses pathalias?

Comment: How odd. What happens if you try "path/val1/val2" in the preview?

Comment: Then I get `path` instead of `val1` and the path value under the query is `path/path/val1/data/val2` :P

Comment: Is this a page view? If so under "Page Settings" is your path value something like "path/%/%" ?

Comment: Yes it is a page view and the path value is like that. Check my first screenshot